# Defining variables in defaultProps in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
class Table extends Component{
  render(){
     return(
        <h2>{props.cal_months}</h2>
     )
   }
}

Table.defaultProps = {
   cal_days :['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
   cal_months : ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April',
                 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
   daysinmonth : [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
   curr : new Date();
};
```

---

I am making a calendar app. I want to define these variables. Is this the correct method to do it in defaultProps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can define these value in `defaultProps`, but it will be better if you define these values as constant variable in same component or in separate file, because `defaultProps` will assign only the default values means values will get changed (overwrite) if you pass any updated value in props.

Check this example:

```js
class Table extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return(
        <h2>{this.props.cal_months}</h2>
     )
   }
}

Table.defaultProps = {
    cal_days :['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    cal_months : ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April',
                  'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    daysinmonth : [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
    curr : new Date(),
};
  
ReactDOM.render(<Table/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Check this passing cal_days in props (overwriting the defaultProps values):

```js
class Table extends React.Component{
     render(){
        return(
           <h2>{this.props.cal_months}</h2>
        )
     }
}

Table.defaultProps = {
    cal_days :['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    cal_months : ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April',
                  'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    daysinmonth : [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
    curr : new Date(),
};
      
ReactDOM.render(<Table  cal_months={['new ', 'values']}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```